# tesseract can't parse my image with text and number

Tags: python-tesseract, tesseract-5.x

I want to get text and number in this football scoreboard image with `tesseract` but didn't work. I have tried these configs but not found an expected result

- Use grayscale image
- `tesseract -psm` mode 1 -> 13

One of the results but not relevant much: `TEE oo We 3:19 &`, I want: MC, DRE and the scores: 0, 0

Here is my image
[image]

Is there any specific config or pre-processing that I need to do? Or even an alternative library that work?